# What is the correct name of points with this property?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $x \in X$.
Suppose for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$ the following inequality holds:
$$
d(x_1, x_2) \le \max \bigl\{ d(x, x_1), d(x, x_2) \bigr\}.
$$
For example, singleton in the Gromov-Hausdorff space satisfies this condition.
And every point in an ultrametric space too.
What is the correct name of points $x$ with this property?

Comment: I do not think there is a name for a particular point in a space with this property. If all $x,x_1,x_2$ in a metric space have this property the space is called ultrametric, but I guess you already know that.

Comment: A somewhat non-trivial notion related to this is that of an *ultrametric skeleton*, see [here](https://cims.nyu.edu/~naor/homepage%20files/skeleton.pdf). Briefly, this is a compact subset of a compact metric space that embeds into an ultrametric space with low distortion.